# Using Cygwin on enterprise-class applications

Tags: windows, linux, cygwin, enterprise

Is Cygwin considered robust and safe enough to be used on enterprise applications? 
Do you know Enterprise applications that were developed or using Cygwin?

If you've been using cygwin - how often did you need support? Is there a fine-support for Cygwin? how well was the support you were given?

Thank you very much.

Comment: why don't you just run linux?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to use Windows for enterprise applications?

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you even consider cygwin towards any sort of enterprise application? Even their site directly gives multiple signs it shouldn't be used for anything critical. You can't run native linux apps and you have to rebuild your app from source if you want it to run. It won't make your apps able to use any *nix functionality like signals, ptys, etc. All it is is a slim Linux type API layer....to answer your question, I don't think anyone would want to use cygwin in an enterprise application.

Like Maz asked, why wouldn't you just run linux? What potential benefits would you ever see coming from cygwin in an enterprise environment?

Comment: Hey and thanks for your reply,
The reason I need cygwin is because i have to run windows and i want to run an SSH server on it.
My intention is not to run cygwin in order to emulate linux - but only to run an open source SSH server.
So I guess the question is - can cygwin & OpenSSH be an enterprise solution for running a well SSH Server on a windows environment?

Comment: Well I imagine it will come down to what purpose you're ultimately trying to serve with it. When you say enterprise application, I imagine something that will take a decent user load and be relied upon. I guess it would just depend on your specific circumstances and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to your question may be obtained from the [Cygwin web site](http://www.cygwin.com/).  The answers obtained there come directly from the maintainers of the Cygwin DLL and ported software.